# Set a custom TraceID in sleuth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I want to set a custom TraceId in sleuth
I try to set traceId in MDC but it does not change the traceId in Span context

```
@GetMapping
public String get() {

    System.out.println("traceId before");
    System.out.println(tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId());

    MDC.put("traceId", "99999");

    log.info("KAFKA: SEND ...");

    System.out.println("traceId after");
    System.out.println(tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId());

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass("test");

    kafkaTemplate.send("test-topic-pp-01", myClass);
    return "Test kafka traceId="+ tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId();

}
```

my kafka listner

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test-topic-pp-01")
public void onMessage(myClass c) {

    System.out.println("traceId kafka");
    System.out.println(tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId());

    log.info("KAFKA: RECEIVE.");

}
```

The output in the console

**traceId before
c934e175e57c6bf5**

**2023-03-14 11:03:08.057  INFO [,99999,c934e175e57c6bf5] 18904 --- [nio-9933-exec-2] m.o.clients.controller.ClientController  : KAFKA: SEND ...**

**traceId after
c934e175e57c6bf5**

**traceId kafka
c934e175e57c6bf5**

**2023-03-14 11:03:08.336  INFO [,c934e175e57c6bf5,ab62017274abae12] 18904 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] m.o.clients.controller.ClientController  : KAFKA: RECEIVE.**

I want to set my traceId to 99999 for example

Any help ?